# spacy summarize model architcture

Tags: spacy

I am new to NLP and neural networks and try to understand the idea behind the spaCy framework. I know how a CNN is working in general. According to [this](https://spacy.io/models/de) German model documentation it´s a multi-task CNN trained on TIGER and WikiNER corpus.

So the model is fed with the corpus as training data and afterwards is able to make for example a POS tagging for my specific sentence.

I am used to it, then it comes to neural networks to study the model summary like for this example below.

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 90, 40)            800000    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 90, 40)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 88, 250)           30250     
_________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling1d_1 (Glob (None, 250)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 250)               62750     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 250)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 250)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 251       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 1)                 0         
=================================================================
```

So I can go through the network and check which layers are applied to it.

I think it´s very importent to check the model architecture to understand how it works. But for spaCy I can´t understand how exactly the model is build. Can you explain the process in a spaCy CNN from loading the training data in, going through the training until a model is created?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to this https://spacy.io/models/de and for that, you can see that the pipeline consists of a tagger, parser and ner.

In spacy's documentation for the models, you can check out the architecture section (https://spacy.io/models) in which the NER model with residual CNNs is explained in a video:
https://youtu.be/sqDHBH9IjRU

Hope that helps.